# Night Light Not Working on LightDm

Tags: lightdm, system-settings, night-light

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2, and recently switched my desktop manager from gdm3 to lightdm because the GUI from gdm3 wasn't working properly after some NVIDIA driver problems. So far, lightdm has been working much better. However, I do have one problem: the Night Light option in Settings > Displays > Night Light is no longer working. I can turn it on, and set manual hours, but it has no visible effect on my desktop. In the top-right corner of the desktop, with the wifi settings and power button, it even says that night light is on. But the desktop looks no different, and changing the "Color Temperature" slider makes no difference. How can I fix this so that Night Light works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around this by installing [redshift](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Redshift), and using the command line to set my screen temperature:

```
sudo apt-get install redshift
redshift -P -O [temperature value between 1000 and 25000]
```

Redshift also has commands for setting the temperature based on longitude & latitude and time of day. A good tool if you're using lightdm!